# How do I remove HTML tags inside an xtable when using knitr?

Tags: html, r, hyperlink, knitr, xtable

When I test an xtable using the following code to print to a separate HTML document, it works fine.

```
print(MyXtable, type = "html", file = "test.html", sanitize.text.function = force)
```

However, when I try to print that same xtable in an R chunk in knitr, the entire string with the html tags is printed within the xtable. Can someone please him me figure it out? This is my Rchunk code.

````
```{r MyXTable, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE, message=F, warning=F}  

MyTable <- data.frame(
                    paste0('<a href="https://mywebsite/', Data$ID, '"target=_blank>Go to Website</a>'),
                    Data$Task,
                    Data$Date
                    )

library(xtable)  
MyXtable<- xtable(MyTable)  
print(MyXtable, include.rownames=FALSE, type = "html",sanitize.text.function = force)

```
````

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was missing the following argument: "comment = FALSE"

````
```{r MyXTable, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE, message=F, warning=F}  

MyTable <- data.frame(
                paste0('<a href="https://mywebsite/', Data$ID, '"target=_blank>Go to Website</a>'),
                Data$Task,
                Data$Date
                )

library(xtable)  
MyXtable<- xtable(MyTable, comment = FALSE)  
print(MyXtable, include.rownames=FALSE, type = "html",sanitize.text.function = force)

```
````